# Janey won't let me into her chest

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I've received the mission *Nova? No Problem!* in Borderlands: The Pre-sequel. The mission requires me to pick up a shield from Janey's chest, and then proceed to do other things; however, the chest has spawned in a container with Janey, and the container has no doors or any other way in. I've searched all around but am unable to find a way into the chest.

This happened while playing multiplayer on the PC version of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply quit out of the game / mission / lobby and log back in. Note that you do not need to close down the entire game, you just need to end your current session and start another session.